# jQuery: How to use fadeToggle()?

Tags: jquery, fade

I want to use jQuery's `fadeToggle()` function.

I have a hidden div and when I click on a link, then I want to call `fadeToggle()` that the div fades in and after another click fades out.

The clue is, that i want to resize the window after clicking with my own function (which is working well).

At the moment I have this solution:

```
jQuery:
$("#myLink").live("click", function () {
   $("#myDiv").toggleClass("myDivClass");
   Resize();
});

Css:
<style type="text/css">
#myDivclass {
display:none;
}
</style>
```

It works perfectly, but I want to do the same thing with `fadeToggle()` instead of `toggleClass()`.

The problem is, that after the second click (after the div has faded out), the window does not resize - it resizes with `toggleClass` but not with `fadeToggle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to supply the `Resize` function as a callback to the `fadeToggle` method, so it runs when the animation is complete:

```
$("#myLink").live("click", function () {
    $("#myDiv").fadeToggle(1000, Resize);
});
```

Note that if you need to pass arguments into the `Resize` function you'll have to use an anonymous callback:

```
$("#myLink").live("click", function () {
    $("#myDiv").fadeToggle(1000, function() {
        Resize();
    });
});
```

On another note, if you're using the latest version of jQuery you definitely shouldn't be using `live`. Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead (and if you're using an older version, [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is still better).

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding resize to the callback function, its possible that the animation hasn't completed by the time `Resize` is called so you don't get the affect you want.

```
$("#myDiv").fadeToggle("fast", function () {
   Resize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you have to wait until the fadeToggle function is completed, try this:

```
$("#myLink").live("click", function () {
  $("#myDiv").fadeToggle('slow', function(){
     Resize();
  });
});
```