# FadeToggle in J Query

Tags: jquery, html

On w3 schools it tells you hot to use FadeToggle effects.

My question is how do I flip the FadeToggle effect so that instead of the boxes showing up when you first see the website, it's gone until you click the box. So kind of like a flip.

Example of the code is here

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_fadetoggle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to use fadeToggle()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292846/jquery-how-to-use-fadetoggle)

Answer (score 1):

All you to do is start faded out:  display:none -> this works:

```
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To have DIVs hidden when your website loads simply use `display:none`.

The application of jQuery's fadeToggle is the same after that. jQuery will change the DIV's display status back and forth from `display:none` to `display:block` no matter which display state you start on.